# "Field: prediction_input.model_name Error: Name should be in the form of 'projects/your-project-id/models/your-model-name'"

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-composer

I'm getting the above error when running `MLEngineStartBatchPredictionJobOperator` in `Google cloud composer`.

But my `model_name is` in the mentioned format, any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the model didn't exist, my bad, but the error could be more explanatory.